# How to swap the blocks using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

By clicking on the button "up" or "down" the block **div with class = poll_row** should change places with earlier or later **div with class = poll_row** and change the value attribute of the hidden field on the +1 or -1

Has the following function:

**assets / javascripts / poll_items.js**

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.down_id', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.sequence').val(parseFloat( $(this).siblings('.sequence').val() ) + 1);
    $(this).parent().next().children('.sequence').val( $(this).parent().next().children('.sequence').val() - 1);
    $(this).closest('.poll_row').insertAfter($(this).closest('.poll_row').next());
  });

  $(document).on('click','.up_id', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.sequence').val(parseFloat( $(this).siblings('.sequence').val() ) -1);
      $(this).parent().prev().children('.sequence').val(parseFloat($(this).parent().prev().children('.sequence').val())+ 1);
    $(this).closest('.poll_row').insertBefore($(this).closest('.poll_row').prev());
  });
```

Clicking the button changes the value of hidden tag.

**But the blocks are reversed only if the double-click of a button. I can not understand what has caused that nothing happens when I first click**

Where is the mistake?

**polls/edit.html.haml**

```
.................................................
.items-index
    = f.simple_fields_for :poll_items do |poll|
      = render 'poll_item_fields', f: poll
.................................................
```

**polls/poll_item_fields.html.haml**

```
.poll_row
  .poll_item
    = f.input :answer, input_html: { class: 'ctrlenter expanding' }, label: false, placeholder: 'Введите вариант ответа'
    = f.hidden_field :sequence, class: 'sequence'
    = button_tag 'вверх', type: 'button', class: 'up_id', value: 'вверх'
    = button_tag 'вниз', type: 'button', class: 'down_id', value: 'вниз'
    - if @poll.editable?(current_user)
      = link_to_remove_association "удалить", f, { wrapper_class: 'poll_item' }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is simply to have reorderable elements and a hidden input with the order of each element there is a far simpler way:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.up_id, .down_id', function() {
  var $el, $row;
  $el = $(this);
  $row = $el.parents('.poll_row');
  // move row up or down one row
  if ( $el.hasClass('up_id') && $row.not(':first-child') ) {
    $row.prev().before($row);
  } 
  else if ( $el.hasClass('down_id') &&  $row.not(':last-child') ) {
    $row.next().after($row);
  }
  // reset the sequence inputs
  $row.parent('.polls').find('.poll_row').each(function(i) {
    var $r = $(this);
    $r.find('.sequence').val($r.index() + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- adding a widget wrapper element makes the DOM traversal much more sane -->
<div class="polls">
  <div class="poll_row" style="background-color: pink">
    <p>Apples</p>
    <input type="number" class="sequence" value=1>
    <button class="up_id">Up</button>
    <button class="down_id">Down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="poll_row" style="background-color: lightgreen">
    <p>Oranges</p>
    <input type="number" class="sequence" value=2>
    <button class="up_id">Up</button>
    <button class="down_id">Down</button>
  </div>
  <div class="poll_row" style="background-color: lightblue">
    <p>Pears</p>
    <input type="number" class="sequence" value=3>
    <button class="up_id">Up</button>
    <button class="down_id">Down</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are several differences in the markup that are purely for demonstration purposes.